# Determine the critical Point $x = x_0$ of a matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the system

$$X'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 2\\0 & -3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}-22\\6\end{bmatrix}$$

determine the critical point $x = x_0$, and then classify its type and examine its stability by making the transformation $x = x_0 + u$

I am unfamiliar with the steps I would take to solve this problem. I have gone as far as to find the eigenvalues of the first matrix, but I do not think that has much relevance to finding the critical points.

Comment: Looks like a problem from control systems . It is better if you ask it on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: What do you mean a problem in control? This is a non-homogeneous DEQ and a dynamical system.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I interpreted what you wrote correctly, we want to find the point where we simultaneously have $x' = y' = 0$

For your system, we would solve:

$$3x+ 2y -22 = 0 \\ 0x -3y + 6 = 0$$

That is the critical point.

We can plot a phase portrait that shows this critical point as:

[image]

Now, you need to do a translation of that per the problem.

Comment: This is far too helpful to go unUVed! +1